# a UIButton defined in a XIB file is not instantiated

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created this view controller which has a XIB file, and contains a `UIButton`.
I alloc and init the controller, and add the view to the superview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.vc = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.vc.view];
    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.height = 200;
    frame.size.width = 200;
    frame.origin.x = 100;
    frame.origin.y = 100;
    self.vc.view.frame = frame;
    [vc setText:@"123"];
}
```

When I run this, the `UIButton` is not shown.  When I debug this, and put breakpoints in my controller's `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`, the `UIButton` is always uninstantiated  (memory adress 00000000);

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyViewController` should be initialised with the XIB file:

```
...
self.vc = [[MyViewController alloc] @"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
...
```

Comment: Thanks :) that was the problem.

Comment: actually the problem was that this XIB file was not loaded. when I tried using this suggested method, I encountered a "nib not found" error. to fix this I included the XIB file in the "Copy Bundled resources" list. However, after I included it, the code worked just with  "init" and I didn't have to use "initWithNibName".